# React Context - Delete user posts (synchronize deletions between routes preserving fetching pagination)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

### INTRODUCTION

I am trying to emulate the typical social networks behavior, where **when the user deletes one of his posts, it is automatically deleted in all the app routes**. Just see the behavior behind Instagram or TikTok.

So, **I have decided to put all the users posts in a context**:

```
export function UserPostsProvider({ children }) {
  const [posts, dispatch] = useReducer(userPostsReducer, initialState);

  const addUserPosts = (userId, posts, unshift = false) => {
    dispatch(actionCreators.addUserPosts(userId, posts, unshift));
  };

  const deleteUserPost = (userId, postId) => {
    dispatch(actionCreators.deleteUserPost(userId, postId));
  };

  const getUserPosts = (userId) => posts[userId] ?? [];

  return (
    <UserPostsContext.Provider
      value={{
        addUserPosts,
        deleteUserPost,
        getUserPosts,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserPostsContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

So, when the user enters another user profile, the posts will be added to this context. Also, when he scrolls down his own endless list of posts, to delete one of his old publications, all the fetched posts (from the database) will be added to the context too.

With this, I am able to delete the posts having a synchronization between all my routes. But... what about RAM and performance?

### PROBLEM

I have detected one PRO and one CONS with this solution:

**PRO:**

*As the all the fetched posts are located inside the context, we can avoid fetching contents that was previously fetched, converting the Context in some kind of in-memory cache.*

**CONS:**

*When the stack screen of another user profile is unmounted, the posts are not deleted from the context... RAM will increase linearly by the pass of the time.*

How can I solve this issue? Any ideas?

Because, if in my components, I just do:

```
function UserPosts({ userData }) {
   const postsContext = useContext(UserPostsContext);

   const posts = postsContext.getUserPosts(userData.id);

   const getMorePosts = () => {
       ... getting posts from DB with pagination
   }

   return <CardList data={posts} ... />
}
```

I will not be able to implement a data pagination at all (only if the posts are not stored in the database), as I am getting all the user posts at once from the context, and the FlatList will render all of them, causing a big performance issue.

Comment: This is a use case for sockets, really should be using sockets instead of context for something like this.  It's a massive UI load to rerender all posts all the time on context updates.

Comment: @Matriarx I decided to store the "dynamic" items in Context as it is useful for synchronize likes, etc. between routes, having a single source of truth. But, definitely, it breaks my data pagination, since I have to render the data taking it from the context in order to be able to erase it in all the components mounted in parallel.And if they are already in context, everything would be rendered at once, without any need to request the database.

Comment: I have also been looking for similar projects in React, but can't find people handling deletions. Some don't even store the data in a context to sync the deletions, just for the syncing of variable data like the number of likes or comments.

Comment: I understand the reasons for using context here, but you will create a ton of work for yourself, every time a post is edited/deleted/added context will refresh everything, if you store all those posts in memory it will be super heavy on the UI, things like your pagination will be difficult, etc.  Instead only store things like "likes" and global truths in context and you can update that through sockets as well, when you update that "likes" it also won't then refresh the entire page and only the little "likes" profile component or whatever you have.

Comment: I'd personally build a little "comment" or "message" component and have that component subscribe to its own sockets for "likes" and "sub comments" or whatever.  No global stuff required there.  Unless you want to display the total likes on a user profile/avatar, then you can update that in context.

Comment: @Matriarx You have saved my life. In fact, with the use of my CardsContext, in which I store the dynamic data of the "Card" components, I can manage the state globally with the necessary data without saturating the memory. Which is just the opposite of storing posts in context, which in a way would negatively impact the performance of the app in a linear way. Listening to the changes in my database (the only source of truth) is what I am going to do to manage this paranoia that would break my pagination if I managed it in a context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments to your question.

My recommendation would be to use sockets for something like this instead of storing everything in context.  Instead context should only be used for things that are truly global and for other things like comments/likes you should instead use sockets to update the incoming/outgoing messages.  For example building a little "comment" or "message" component and letting each of them subscribe to their own socket.

What's more is that if you're working with something like "likes" or "comments" then the only way to get it to update in real time is using sockets or spamming your backend with constant requests.

For that you'll need to add sockets to your API, so in a route like "comment/9283012/like" or whatever, you can publish a "like" event (or whatever) that the other users or a specific user can listen to, which in return will update the specific "comment" or "message" component that you created.

Comment: For likes and comments, I work with context + pull-to-refresh. For other more complex stuff, listening db is cool, in order to avoid RAM problems.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1. use pagination instead of loading all the posts in one request. with scroll down/scroll up, the new requests will send to the server and get the tail of data. for example, you can get the old post with an offset of 10 posts per request or more. also with CDN cash and a proper cash policy you can manage a pro application like Instagram.
2. you can define a method (action) to clear the context value on page unload in the `useEffect` clean up function:

for example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  return () => // here call the cleaner function
}, [])
```

Comment: yeah, I am using paginated requests, the main problem is when the user gets the data from context. Anyways, I will try to clean the context when the component unmounts. Will not be as easier, as in my app I have multiple tabs with multiple stacks, and I will have to synchronize cursors or something like that between the routes if the user has the profile of another one opened in different routes.